# Reverse engineering a matrix in RREF

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I know that multiple matrices can have the same RREF, but a matrix has a unique RREF, I am trying to reverse engineer a 3x3 RREF matrix to get an abstract matrix of the same size that has 2 columns known, but am really confused how to do so, as I am only able to get one solution when multiple solutions exist.
For example what I am trying to do if that given an RREF and 2 columns find the third one.

Comment: Your question is not clear in its current form. Apparently you're trying to "reverse engineer a 3x3 RREF matrix"; I think this means that you're trying to find the RREF using the information that you have about a matrix (which does not entail knowing all of the matrix's entries). What exactly is the information that you have about this matrix?

Comment: Do you mean you are given the RREF, and the two known columns, and you want the third column?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes exactly!

Answer (score 1):

For example, suppose the RREF is

$$ \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 1\cr
            0 & 1 & 1\cr
            0 & 0 & 0\cr}$$

and your matrix with first two columns known is supposed to be
$$ \pmatrix{1 & 2 & x\cr
            3 & 4 & y\cr
            5 & 6 & z\cr} $$

Now the RREF has the same null space as the original matrix, in this case the span of $$\pmatrix{1\cr 1\cr -1}$$
That says
$$  \pmatrix{1 & 2 & x\cr
            3 & 4 & y\cr
            5 & 6 & z\cr}  \pmatrix{1\cr 1\cr -1\cr} = \pmatrix{3 - x\cr 7 - y\cr 11 - z\cr} = \pmatrix{0\cr 0\cr 0\cr} $$
from which you can read out $x,y,z$.

Here there is just one solution.